# how to upload images inside a complex json object to asp from js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, image, file-upload

i'm able to send images with formdata from js to asp web api but i don't know how to do it with json object when the images are in objects as properties

i have these classes in asp:

```
     public class SessionExam
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public decimal max { get; set; }
            public decimal min { get; set; }
            public int duration { get; set; }
            public List<SessionExamQuestion> questions { get; set; }
        }

     public class SessionExamQuestion
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public decimal mark { get; set; }
            public List<SessionExamQuestionOption> options { get; set; }
            public byte[] image { get; set; }
        }

     public class SessionExamQuestionOption
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public bool isRight { get; set; }
        }
```

SessionExamQuestion class has image property as array of bytes

how can i send images from javascript using ajax to asp web api?

i used to send images as multipart to asp

thanks in advance guys